# Correct Way to Validate Employer's Pilot Program That Has Already Been "Completed"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, experiment-design

Suppose my employer is a grocery store chain and they keep track of the satisfaction of their customers. The data is binomial; that is, all customers report that they were either satisfied or unsatisfied with their shopping on their way out.

The business just finished a one-month-long pilot program at one of the stores to increase the proportion of satisfied customers (total number of customers is not important -- they just want a high proportion of "satisfied" customers). Most of the 30 stores have approximately 400 customers daily.

What is the best way to see if the pilot program was successful:

Should we look at how the proportion of satisfied customers at this one store has changed over time? What if the total number of customers or proportion of satisfied customers is seasonal?

Or, should we compare this store's proportion of satisfied customers to some/all of the other stores' proportions of satisfied customers? What if the proportion of satisfied customers varies between store locations? Is it "okay" then to choose a control store(s) based on data prior to applying the treatment?

Finally, once we have decided to compare a store to itself in the past or to compare it to an analog store at the same time, what is the correct significance test to use?

If the data were smaller, could it be fit into a 2x2 contingency table for a Fisher's Exact Test? Or, would it be better to look at the proportion of satisfied customers at a weekly resolution so that there is a mean proportion and standard deviation of proportions to fit into a 2-sample z-test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exploit all the data you have by including all the stores (both the experimental store and the other stores), measured both before and after the intervention, in a single model. A suitably constructed regression model will be able to distinguish the change over time in the experimental store (which is the closest you can get to estimating the effect of the intervention in this non-experimental design) from the changes over the same period of time in the other stores. For example, you could use a mixed model with a per-store random intercept, an effect of time, a dummy variable indicating the control store, and a term (or more than one term, depending on how you code time) for the interaction between this dummy variable and time. Then it's the interaction term that estimates the effect of the intervention.

Comment: Thank you. I have run in to some unexpected results: I was working on this in excel and I applied a linear regression to data collected from the test store before treatment and after. Using the slopes and standard errors for the slopes, I did a single sample t-test for each regression to see if the slope was significantly different from zero, and for both I obtained a p-value of almost 1. A 2 sample z test comparing both slopes yielded a small p-value, however. Is a regression model appropriate if it appears the data is not time-dependent?

Comment: I'm out of practice in statistics, but in case it is helpful to know, I plotted a histogram of the daily satisfaction rates and the data appears normally distributed.

Comment: @PNNoel When you write "slopes", which predictor are you referring to the slopes of? Also, you ought to use logistic regression or probit regression rather than linear regression, since the dependent variable is dichotomous. If you code the dependent variable into rates, as you've done here, then the model can't tell the difference between 1 out of 3 and 1,000 out of 3,000 satisfied customers.

Comment: Thank you, @Kodiologist. Like I said, I am out of practice, but I see now why plotting daily "satisfaction proportion" against time is not as useful as logistic regression. When I said "slope" I was referring to the slope of the line of best fit through the plotted daily satisfaction proportion vs time. I think that the next step is to compare logistic regressions between stores to see if the change in proportion of satisfied customers at the pilot store is different from the change in proportion of satisfied customers at other stores.